# Check if single element is in a list in LINQ when the single is provided first

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ to SQL for a service in a project. I have three entities involved: `PCode` is a property of `PurchaseOrder`, as well as in an M:N with `User`.

```
PCode (M:N) User
PCode (1:M) PurchaseOrder
```

The service is for `PurchaseOrder`, so that table is being queried. Because of that, using `.Where()` requires `p => p.PCode` at the beginning to utilize the value. I know of `.Contains()` and the other similar commands, but they all require that the list come first and I can't do that with this type of query. I ultimately need to check whether the `PCodeId` in the specific `PurchaseOrder` is in the list of `PCodeId`s associated with the current user. How can I filter this way in LINQ to SQL? I feel like this is really simple, I just can't figure it out.

Simplified `User` class:

```
public partial class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PCode> PCodes { get; set; }
}
```

`PCode`:

```
public partial class PCode
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

`PurchaseOrder`:

```
public partial class PurchaseOrder
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int PCodeId { get; set; }
}
```

Beginning of query:

```
// list to be searched can either be passed into the function
// or retrieved via navigation property when the query runs, either works

var query = _poRepository.Table;
if (condition)
    // query = query.Where( ? );
    // query = query.Where(p => p.PCode ... ? );
```

Comment: @RobertMcKee Just clarified that in the question, sorry. I ultimately need to check whether the `PCodeId` in the specific `PurchaseOrder` is in the list of `PCodeId`s associated with the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var CurrentUser=db.Users
  .Include(u=>u.PCodes)
  .Where(u=>u.id==something);
if (CurrentUser.PCodes.Any(pc=>...))
```

You are also missing navigation properties on Purchase Order, and PCode:

```
public partial class PurchaseOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // Should not be virtual
    public int PCodeId { get; set; } // Should not be virtual
    public virtual PCode PCode { get; set; } // new Navigation
}
public partial class PCode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // Should not be virtual
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrders> PurchaseOrders { get; set; } // new Navigation
}
```

Or the reverse:

```
var po=db.PurchaseOrders
  .Include(po=>po.PCode)
  .Include(po=>po.PCode.Users)
  .First(po=>po.id==someid);

if (po.PCode.Users.Contains(currentUser)) ... 
or
if (po.PCode.Users.Any(u=>u.id==someuserid)) ...
```

or if all you have is a userid and poid:

```
if (db.PurchaseOrders.Any(po=>po.id==poid && po.PCode.Users.Any(u=>u.id==userid))) ...
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I completely forgot the navigation property for `User` on `PlannerCode`, that would've made it much easier. I went with `(po.PCode.Users.Any(u=>u.id==someuserid))`, I think that's the simplest to implement. Thank you!